# Angular 6 circular dependency "Can't resolve all parameters"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use an external module in my application and getting the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for Computus in
>   /usr/local/app/node_modules/ng-computus/dist/services/computus/computus.service.d.ts:
>   (?).

After reading around all the other posts about this error it seems the `(?)` is a tell-tale sign of a circular dependency.

However, I can't see where that would be coming from. The `computus` module has four classes. A superclass called `Calendar` which is extended by two other classes `Gregorian` and `Julian`. The fourth class `Computus` handles the returning of instances of the two classes via an API.

The library is very basic and none of the classes have circular dependencies on each other. The source code is viewable at https://github.com/ATNU/ng-computus/tree/master/src/services

In my application, I import in the standard way

```
import { Computus } from "ng-computus";
```

And attempt to use it like so

```
computus = new Computus(1600);
```

What is the best way to debug in a situation like this? The resolve all parameters message is particularly unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this in stackblitz and I don't get any error. Maybe there is another problem ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6pddh

Comment: That's strange! At least it shows there's nothing wrong with the ng-computus library. I've imported the library and used it in exactly the same way and still have the error. Could it be something to do with versioning of Angular or Babel? The only other libraries I'm using are Angular Material.